# How to create separate tables in VBA word?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am trying to create two separate tables in VBA

I've checked a lot of threads, but can't figure it out. Keep getting an error. I am able to create the first table, or create a second table nested in the first one, but is unable to create two separate tables.

```
Dim objWord
Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
objWord.Visible = True
Set oDoc = objWord.Documents.Add
Set oTable = oDoc.Tables.Add(oDoc.Range(0, 0), 6, 4)

oDoc.Paragraphs.Add
Set aRange = ActiveDocument.Paragraphs.Last.Range

Set oTable2 = oDoc.Tables.Add(oDoc.aRange, 5, 4)

oTable.Borders.Enable = True
oTable2.Borders.Enable = True
```

The line `Set oTable2 = oDoc.Tables.Add(oDoc.aRange, 5, 4)` gets an error. I am not sure what to do about the `aRange` that was declared earlier.

Comment: Just change the two lines to
`Set aRange = oDoc.Paragraphs.Last.Range` :
`Set oTable2 = oDoc.Tables.Add(aRange, 5, 4)` and it will work fine.  Also better declare all the objects and variables. Since `aRange` has been already defined no need to refer to as `oDoc.aRange`

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
Dim wdApp As Object, wdDoc As Object, wdTbl As Object
Set wdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
With wdApp
  .Visible = True
  Set wdDoc = .Documents.Add
  With wdDoc
    Set wdTbl = .Tables.Add(.Range.Characters.Last, 6, 4)
    wdTbl.Borders.Enable = True
    .Range.InsertAfter vbCr
    Set wdTbl = .Tables.Add(.Range.Characters.Last, 5, 4)
    wdTbl.Borders.Enable = True
  End With
End With
```

Comment: Thanks!  also can you please teach me how to write things into these cells?

Comment: Start a new thread, telling us what you have tried. This is not a VBA tutoring service.